# Why doesn't my web page load completely every time?

Tags: windows, asp.net, iis, website

I have an intranet website running on IIS 7. When I try to load my site, it reacts differently every time. Here are the following different scenarios that occur when I try to load my site:

1. The site loads right away and is working properly
2. The site loads slowly and some my styling/images/javascript did not appear to load correctly.
3. I receive a "503 service unavailable" error

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like your website might be getting overloaded with traffic.

Comment: how can i check if t@z the case???

Comment: Logs, counters, etc. More of a server admin question, really.

Comment: 1) Who is t@z?  
2) You don't provide enough details to advise you.  
3) It IS mostly admin question, so this is wrong place to ask.

Comment: It's not necessarily your website, it might be anything else that is clogging the server's resources. What you should do is open Task Manager on your server, and see if there's any process using up your CPU or memory.

Comment: the thing is, we are using the latest blade servers in our production environment and this started happening after a new website was hosted. (all websites are hosted in this particular server is having this problem now ) so could it possibly be due to network traffic?? could anything related to IIS cause this problem???

Answer (score 1):

So finally my problem was solved. The problem was in the IIS configuration, the maximum number of connections was set to 5. Simply increasing it solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

full description of the error:

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

One thing that can happen on your server is that all 80+ ports the server receives taking precedence over port 80. The same port your website runs on.

Here's a command to see if this is true (run it in `cmd`):

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

if you get an entry something like this:

```
Reserved URL : http://+:80/
...
```

Then this means that the above issue is happening to you. And you need to remove the record from there with this command

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80/
```

sources:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/21/the-iis-7-team-rocks.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/18/service-unavailable-errors-in-iis-7-are-killing-me.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your first step in determining why this is happening is gathering information.

If you have access to the server physically or via RDP, you can use `perfmon` to analyze the server performance.

Here are some articles on how to do so (note that these are for 2003, but it really hasn't changed much for 2008/2008 R2):

[Using the System Monitor (PerfMon) with ASP.NET Applications (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b4d4d195-2ecb-4728-9348-6f1bfa1a1b63.mspx?mfr=true)

[Performance Counters for IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4427ad2b-c33b-4b5f-b18a-16568349149a.mspx?mfr=true)

After you gather information on what's happening performance wise, you can then begin to isolate the cause.